# Resolved: php condition block JS addEventListener

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, addeventlistener

i have a php condition who do appear or disappear a button (need a user role).
The window is reloaded when you login and the button appear.

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['role']) && $_SESSION['role'] === 'admin') : ?>
       <div id="btn-crea" class="icon-user-bx"></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

i wants to apply a JS event listener on this button to remove a class to a modal (to do it appear).

```
const modalCreaCont = document.querySelector(".connexion-modal-crea-container");
const closeModalCreaBtn = document.querySelector(".close-modal-crea");
const creaBtn = document.getElementById("btn-crea");

function showModalCrea() {
  modalCreaCont.classList.remove("hidden");
}

function closeModalCrea() {
  modalCreaCont.classList.add("hidden");
}

//open creation modal
creaBtn.addEventListener("click", showModalCrea);
```

With this code Nothing happens.

If i use another button (without condition): the event is working.

If i pull the condition off: the event is working.

i am desperate. Can you help me...

Comment: is your condition part of an ajax request? or the initial page load.

Comment: Try putting that javascript code at the bottom of your page right before the `</body>`

Comment: This not a part of a ajax request but there is one juste after (to process the modal's form).

Comment: Of course, the script is linked juste before the </body>.

Comment: Unless the div is added to the page by ajax, i see no reason the php condition serving or not serving it would affect the event binding. I suspect it actually is added via ajax.

Comment: The AJAX after serve only to post some input value. The div is in a php file not in the JS one.

Answer (score 0):

I have find the problem.

Before my button, there was another button with condition (and event listener) and when your are logedin this button is hidden so the event listner stop the script because it can't find the button.

I have separate my script in two part and i had move the part concerning the problematic button before the other part.